# Validate the two field using jquery validator

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

[image]I want to validate the two field like passing marks is always less than full marks using **validator plugin** method.

**Note:: My Html Field is dynamic so, not consider as a single field.**

**Here is below my Html field.**

```
<td>
  <div class="form-group">

      <input type="text" name="fmark_<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" class="form-control" id="fmark_<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $value['full_marks'] ?>" placeholder="Enter Full Marks">
  </div>
</td>
<td>
  <div class="form-group">

      <input type="text" name="pmarks_<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" class="form-control" id="pmarks_<?php echo $value['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $value['passing_marks'] ?>" placeholder="Enter Passing Marks">
  </div>
</td>
```

**And Here below is my jquery validator.**

```
$('input[id^="fmark_"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Required"
        }
    });
});
$('input[id^="pmarks_"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Required"
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jQueryValidate this is easily done by creating a validator like the following for example.  (you may want a better way to get your fmark id to the variable "id".  The way you have your code written you would have to parse text to match the id which is not ideal.)

```
$.validator.addMethod("lessThanFullMarks",
function (value, event, params) {
    var id = 'fmark_'+params;
    return parseInt(value) < parseInt($('#'+id).val()); });
});
```

Then to use it just add it to the rules and messages, like this.

```
$('input[id^="fmark_"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Required"
        }
    });
});
$('input[id^="pmarks_"]').each(function () {
    $(this).rules('add', {
        required: true,
        lessThanFullMarks: ["<PUT THE MATCHING FULL MARK ID HERE>"],
        messages: {
            required: "Required",
            lessThanFullMarks: "Must be greater than Full Marks."
        }
    });
});
```

Just my personal preference, but I think applying rules to the form is a little cleaner and more flexible than running an each on matching selectors. Here is an example from one of my projects where I do that.

```
$("#createContractForm").validate({
            rules: {
                Name: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 50
                },
                ContractNumber: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 100
                },
                InitialValue: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 1,
                    number: true
                },
                SourcingDate: {
                    required: true,
                    validDate: true,
                    date: true
                },
                EffectiveDate: {
                    required: true,
                    validDate: true,
                    date: true,
                    greaterThanSourcingDate: true
                },
                EndDate: {
                    required: true,
                    validDate: true,
                    date: true,
                    greaterThanEffectiveDate: true
                },
                ChampionId: {
                    required: true
                },
                CategoryId: {
                    required: true
                },
                SubcategoryId: {
                    required: true
                },
                Details: {
                    required: true
                },
                ClientId: {
                    required: true
                },
                ClientRegionId: {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: $("#urlContractExists").data("request-url"),
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            ClientId: function () {
                                return $("#ClientId").val();
                            },
                            ClientRegionId: function () {
                                return $("#ClientRegionId").val();
                            },
                            CategoryId: function () {
                                return $("#CategoryId").val();
                            },
                            SubcategoryId: function () {
                                return $("#SubcategoryId").val();
                            },
                            SupplierId: function () {
                                return $("#SupplierId").val();
                            },
                            SupplierRegionId: function () {
                                return $("#SupplierRegionId").val();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                SupplierId: {
                    required: true
                },
                SupplierRegionId: {
                    required: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: $("#urlContractExists").data("request-url"),
                        type: "post",
                        data: {
                            ClientId: function () {
                                return $("#ClientId").val();
                            },
                            ClientRegionId: function () {
                                return $("#ClientRegionId").val();
                            },
                            CategoryId: function () {
                                return $("#CategoryId").val();
                            },
                            SubcategoryId: function () {
                                return $("#SubcategoryId").val();
                            },
                            SupplierId: function () {
                                return $("#SupplierId").val();
                            },
                            SupplierRegionId: function () {
                                return $("#SupplierRegionId").val();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            messages: {
                Name: {
                    required: "Contract Name is required"
                },
                ContractNumber: {
                    required: "Contract Number is required"
                },
                InitialValue: {
                    required: "Initial Value is required",
                    number: "Initial Value must be a number"
                },
                SourcingDate: {
                    required: "Sourcing Date is required",
                    date: "Sourcing Date must be a valid date"
                },
                EffectiveDate: {
                    required: "Effective Date is required",
                    date: "Effective Date must be a valid date",
                    greaterThanSourcingDate: "Effective Date must be greater than the Sourcing Date"
                },
                EndDate: {
                    required: "End Date is required",
                    date: "End Date must be a valid date",
                    greaterThanEffectiveDate: "End Date must be greater than the Effective Date"
                },
                ChampionId: {
                    required: "A Champion is required"
                },
                CategoryId: {
                    required: "A Category is required"
                },
                SubcategoryId: {
                    required: "A Subcategory is required"
                },
                Details: {
                    required: "Deatils are required"
                },
                ClientId: {
                    required: "Client is required"
                },
                ClientRegionId: {
                    required: "Client Region is required",
                    remote: "Contract for the same Category, Subcategory, Client Region, and Supplier Region already exists."
                },
                SupplierId: {
                    required: "Supplier is required"
                },
                SupplierRegionId: {
                    required: "Supplier Region is required",
                    remote: "Contract for the same Category, Subcategory, Client Region, and Supplier Region already exists."
                }
            },
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).closest(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
            },
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass: "help-block",
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                if (element.parent(".input-group").length) {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                } else {
                    error.insertAfter(element);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, minor modified in your jquery add method and working fine.Thank you for your help...

Comment: great.  let me know what modifcation you made and I'll update the answer.  Thanks for the checkmark!

Comment: your script is modified.
$.validator.addMethod("lessThanFullMarks",
    function (value, event, params) {

        var id = 'fmark_'+params;
        
        return parseInt(value) < parseInt($('#'+id).val());
    });